# "godef: There must be at least one package that contains the file" even though the file does have a package?

Tags: go, visual-studio-code

I'm using VS Code with the Go extension, but I noticed that when I right-click on a method and select "Go to definition", no definition is found. For example,

[image]

This is in a sample app I generated using Cobra:

```
cobra init myCobraApp --pkg-name=github.com/khpeek/myCobraApp
```

I would expect this to work because the `myCobraApp` directory is organized like

```
.
├── LICENSE
├── cmd
│   └── root.go
└── main.go
```

where `cmd/root.go` contains

```
package cmd

import (
  "fmt"
  "os"
  "github.com/spf13/cobra"

  homedir "github.com/mitchellh/go-homedir"
  "github.com/spf13/viper"

)


var cfgFile string


// rootCmd represents the base command when called without any subcommands
var rootCmd = &cobra.Command{
  Use:   "myCobraApp",
  Short: "A brief description of your application",
  Long: `A longer description that spans multiple lines and likely contains
examples and usage of using your application. For example:

Cobra is a CLI library for Go that empowers applications.
This application is a tool to generate the needed files
to quickly create a Cobra application.`,
  // Uncomment the following line if your bare application
  // has an action associated with it:
  //    Run: func(cmd *cobra.Command, args []string) { },
}

// Execute adds all child commands to the root command and sets flags appropriately.
// This is called by main.main(). It only needs to happen once to the rootCmd.
func Execute() {
  if err := rootCmd.Execute(); err != nil {
    fmt.Println(err)
    os.Exit(1)
  }
}
```

I've also tried to invoke `godef` from the command line, but I get this error message:

```
~/g/s/g/k/myCobraApp> godef -f main.go "cmd.Execute()"
godef: There must be at least one package that contains the file
```

I don't understand this error message: isn't there a package that contains the file?

Comment: please share `pwd` `go env` `go version`

Answer (score 1):

It turns out this functionality was broken by setting the `GO111MODULE` environment variable to `on` in my `~/.config/fish/config.fish`. When I removed this, the 'Go-To Definition' button worked again.

Answer (score 0):

ERROR: godef: There must be at least one package that contains the file.

[image]

It seems like in go 1.16 env variable (GO111MODULE) is set `auto/on`.

You can turn it off the GO111MODULE by simply exporting the env var.

```
export GO111MODULE=off
```